# Netsuite: ReferenceError functionName is not defined

Tags: netsuite

This is probably a stupid one but I have tried all the things I can think of. I am currently getting the below error on my client side script when I try and execute it.

**Error: ReferenceError acvt_serialNumber_saveRecord is not defined**

On the Script record in Netsuite I have set the saveRecord function as follows:
acvt_serialNumber_saveRecord

The code in the file is:

```
function acvt_serialNumber_saveRecord(){
    /**do stuff */
}
```

I have reuploaded to code to make sure the right version was in NetSuite. I have added one character to both the script fn name and the fn name on the Script record (as a shot in the dark). I have seen in the Javascript console at runtime that the correct code is in there and I can see the exact function name (I did a ctrl+f for the "undefined" function in the code in the console to make sure spelling was all the same).

NOTHING has worked. I had this code working earlier, but the changes I made were not to this function at all.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this being saved on the form or is it a client script?

Comment: Not sure, but I guess you probably have misplaced the function name some where. Just make sure that the function name that you put is in the correct context. I mean if you are looking to trigger this function on save then put the function name `acvt_serialNumber_saveRecord` in the `SAVE RECORD FUNCTION` box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing to check is the code that you recently changed. In particular, check for a hanging comma. IE:

```
var someObj = {
    someProp:'somevalue',
};
```

The comma at the end of 'somevalue' will cause the script to fail, throwing 'undefined' errors.

Comment: Hallelujah!! Thank you! It wasn't quite having an extra comma, it was missing a comma when I was declaring several variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the Script record in NetSuite and re-creating it?

Comment: I hadn't tried before. I just did. Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any library included for that Client Script in netsuite ?
Provide a screen shot of your Netsuite script page

I encounter similar problem like this before, but it was because i called a function which is inside a library file

Thanks